# Grails: Using builder pattern to create a bean

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

I’m trying to create a bean that uses a builder. I’m trying to do it within a doWithSpring closure in a plugin config file like so but I’m not sure of the exact syntax:

```
def doWithSpring = {
        appSettingsZKClient(CuratorFramework) { bean ->
            bean.builder()
                .namespace(APP_SETTINGS_NAMESPACE)
                .connectString(application.config.zookeeper.connect.url)
                .retryPolicy(new RetryNTimes(10, 1000))
                .build()
        }
    }
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice idea [Simple Builder - example](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/groovy-goodness-create-simple-builders.html), but generally the groovy guys used to using DSLs([groovy dsls](http://groovy-lang.org/dsls.html)) to build complex objects.